# TFS Aggregator - how automatically modify a field value when a link is manually added to a workitem

Tags: tfs, tfs-aggregator

I'm using TFS 2017 update 1 on premises.
Is there any way with TFS Aggregator to automatically modify a field value when a link (e.g. parent/child, related ecc.) is manually added to a workitem by TFS Web Interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to identify the value changes of the field "**Related Link Count**"

When you add a Related work link to a work item, the field "Related Link Count" will be changed accordingly. (`refname="System.RelatedLinkCount"`)

So, you can set the rules to modify a field value automatically based on the "**Related Link Count**" field changes.

First, try to follow the steps of installation on this website to install the plugin: https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/wiki/Install

Then create the rules accordingly. Below are the samples you can reference:

- [Has any one used TFS AGGREGATOR for implementing below scenarios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779922/has-any-one-used-tfs-aggregator-for-implementing-below-scenarios)

More information please refer to this link: 
https://tfsaggregator.github.io/using/policy-examples/

Comment: @user3676571 Is that helpful for you? have you resolved your issue?